# How to create big size billboards?

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I need to creat a billboard that is 7m width and 3m height.

I started in Photoshop, and after I saw that the clean file is about 18gb, i said like hmmmm... Then i tried Adobe illustrator but it allows maximum file width 577,95cm which is 5.7m.

How can create the billboard?

Comment: As it currently stands, the question is not a programming one - You may get a better response on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Billboards that big are usually printed in very low resolution. For image that size you will probably need no more than 15-30 DPI and it will drastically reduce your file size.